# What should be the constructor properties value ..a prototypes constructor or the objects constructor itself

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Question:Why is the constructor of p1 coming out to be Person.Shouldn't it be Man ?

```
function Person()
{
 this.type='person'
}
function Man()
{
 this.type='Man'
}

Man.prototype=new Person();

var p1=new Man();
console.log('p1\'s constructor is:'+p1.constructor);
console.log('p1 is instance of Man:'+(p1 instanceof Man));
console.log('p1 is instance of Person:'+(p1 instanceof Person));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GSXVX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You destroyed the original `.constructor` property when overwrote the original `prototype` object...

```
Man.prototype = new Person();
```

You can manually replace it, but it will be an enumerable property unless you make in non-enumerable (in ES5 implementations).

```
Man.prototype=new Person();
Man.prototype.constructor = Man; // This will be enumerable.
```

---

```
  // ES5 lets you make it non-enumerable
Man.prototype=new Person();
Object.defineProperty(Man.prototype, 'constructor', {
    value: Man,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
});
```

Comment: Well you said original prototype object(i.e.Man.prototype) was overwritten .But in the prototype chain we start from the bottom.So  the object's (p1's) constructor property should be checked first which is not overwritten.Why would we even go and check for prototype's constuctor property if it exists for the object itself ?

Comment: @kaioken: The `p1` object doesn't have a `.constructor` property of its own. Or at least the code in your question doesn't assign one. It gets its `.constructor` property from the prototype chain. Because you overwrote the original prototype object for `Man`, and didn't reassign the `.constructor` property manually, it continues down the chain to the prototype object of the new `Man.prototype` object, which is `Person.prototype`, which still has its original `.constructor` property. If that one was removed, it would continue down the chain until one *(or none)* was found.